# R: length(abs(t1)>1.97) it returns total number

Tags: r

[image: code]

I am trying to compute the length of absolute values > 1.97 in t1, but it always returns the total number of `t1`. How to deal with this problem?
[image: data]

Answer (score 3):

`length` would always return the same number as `t1`. To count how many values in `t1` is greater than 1.97 use `sum`.

```
t1_reject <- sum(abs(t1)>1.97)
```

For example in below vector trying to count number of values greater than 5.

```
x <- 1:10

length(x > 5)
#[1] 10

sum(x > 5)
#[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `length(abs(t1>1.97))` with a subset instead, i.e.  `t1[abs(t1)>1.97]` to get the number of values that are greater than 1.97.

```
t1 <- c(2.98, 1.96, 1.97, 2.26)

length(t1[abs(t1)>1.97])/length(t1)
```

So the result is 0.5 for the example above.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
sum( t1 > 1.97 | t1 < -1.97)
```